# Has the question about antiderivates vanished?

Tags: support, specific-question, search

I noticed a question on this forum, whether functions are known, for which it is known that a closed-form antiderivate exists, but the antiderivate is unknown.

Since this question would interest me as well, I wonder whether this question was deleted. I could not find it anymore.

To repeat the question

> Are there functions with unknown antiderivates known to have a closed-form antiderivate ?

The answer should be no, since the Risch-algorithm finds the antiderivate, if it exists, but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you mean [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983278/integrals-that-have-yet-to-be-solved-are-there-any)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, thank you!

Comment: peter, as you have over 10k, if you put a question in your Favorites list on Main, it remains on that list regardless of who deletes it; the listing is then outlined in a different color, possibly pink. Also, if an under 10k user favorites a post but it is deleted, they can no longer see it in their own favorites list but you can see it in their list by going to their profile.